# Using labels without loops in onBindviewHolder

Tags: java, android, label

I am trying to use this code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    label :{ 
        if(some condition) {
            //my code
        } else {
            if(my condition) {
                //some code
                continue label; // from here i want to go back to label, how to i go?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the line continue label;  gives me this error : **not a loop label**

so i need to go back to the line "label" How do i do that?

Comment: Did you try the while loop solution I posted?

Comment: it is not working as it is in on bindview

Comment: Could you better explain then what are you trying to achieve? If you want to programatically call the onBindViewHolder() method you can do it by using bindVIewHolder(). See more at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH, int)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have to use the "label" loop?

Try using a while loop, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    while (true) {
        if (some condition) {
            // my code
            break; // if this code ran then exit the while loop
        } else if (my condition) {
            // some code
            continue; // from here it will make another iteration in the while loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but this is in onbindviewholder, how can i put it in while loop?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria I edited the code to make it clearer. You just put the while loop inside the onBindViewHolder() method. Is there something else that isn't clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **continue keyword** used to skip the iteration in the loop.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    while (true) { 
        if(some condition) {
            //my code
        } else {
            if(my condition) {
                //some code
              continue ; // skipping this iteration
            }
        }
    }
}
```